# Calculate cell dimensions given the positions in a finite grid

Tags: algorithm

I did a search on whether this has been asked before but I could not find any similar question. This is more of a algorithmic question and is not confined to any particular programming language. So, my question is as follows.

**Data given**:

1. A rectangular grid, 'G' of fixed width and height: (W, H).
2. An array, 'A1', of absolute positions of 'n' blocks in the grid: A1 = [(x0,
   y0), (x1, y1), ..., (xn-1, yn-1)].
3. Each and every block in the array is a simple rectangle with 4 edges.
4. The sum of areas of all the blocks in the array 'A1' =
   total area of the grid 'G', in other words, the array 'A1' has as many
   blocks as it takes to fill the entire grid 'G'.
5. The positions in the array 'A1' are not arranged in any particular order.
6. Position values represent upper-left corners of the blocks.
7. None of the blocks overlap.

**Problem**: Calculate size(width and height) of each block. i.e., calculate (w0, h0), (w1, h1), ..., (wn-1, hn-1).

I feel this problem can be generalized to a space of any dimension.

Comment: How are the positions in A1 related to the placement of the blocks?

Comment: Does it really matter, I mean all position values follow the same relation to their respective blocks.

Comment: @FearLeslie It would absolutely make a difference if, say, the positions in A1 are the lower left corners of respective blocks vs. the centers of blocks or the top right corners of blocks...

Comment: @twalberg: In that case I'd say the positions are upper-left corners of the blocks.

Comment: For most instances there will be a vast number of possible solutions.  E.g. suppose all n blocks have x co-ord 0, and various distinct y co-ords in increasing order.  One solution fills the grid with n full-width non-overlapping blocks.  But for any i <= n, we could make block i 1 unit taller, so that it overlaps the top row of block i+1, and make any other block j != i 1 unit shorter.  This can even be done multiple times.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I would guess that the intention is no overlap, based on the "sum of areas of rectangles = total area of grid" constraint, although that requires a bit of reading between the lines, because that's obviously not exactly an equivalent constraint...

Comment: @j_random_hacker: as tawlberg pointed out, there is no overlap. Fixed the OP with this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see now that you are looking for a way to *partition* the grid into rectangular blocks having given upper-left corners.  However, in general there is still more than one way to do this.  E.g. given the 3 upper-left corners A, B and C in the 4x4 grid on the left below, either of the two sets of blocks to its right solves the problem:

```
A.B.    AaBb    AaBb
....    aabb    aabb
C...    Ccbb    Cccc
....    ccbb    cccc
```

You can make a larger grid from as many copies of this grid as you like.  A grid made from k copies (and thus using 3k blocks) will have 2^k distinct solutions.

Also, a particular problem instance need not have any solution.  For example, at least one grid square is left uncovered by the problem instance on the left:

```
A.      Aa      A.
.B      .B      aB
```

Comment: This is an edit of my previous comment: I hadn't considered a possibility of something like what you pointed out in the first part of your reply. That part is very true. The situation like what you mentioned in the second part of your reply would not arise since there would always be enough blocks whose total area sum will be equal to the total grid area. In light of the first part of your reply, the problem definition now requires more information to have an unique solution. So my question now is what could that information be?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind I'm afraid.  Part of it stems from the fact that in this example, (2, 2) (0-based co-ords) could be filled either "down" from B or "right" from A.  But when there is more than one such "decision", then making one choice might have implications for choices in other parts of the grid, which is what makes it difficult.

Comment: The problem can have a unique solution if we're given either the width or the height of every block but that kind of defeats the purpose of the problem. Anyway, I'll accept your reply as a valid answer. Thanks for your time, really appreciate it :)

Comment: You're welcome! But I wouldn't be upset if you unaccepted this answer, as it doesn't give a complete solution. I would at least wait a few more days, to see if nothing more definitive comes along :)